# Abbreviation of "depth"

Tags: abbreviations

What is the abbreviation of "depth"? I found DPT and D. Sometimes they were accompanied by periods, other times not. Any help?

Answer (score 1):

Volume = width x height x depth: v=whd

I'd just use "d".  But on first use, call it out with parenthesis:  "The object is 12 inches in depth(d)..."